# Is it possible to tell if cookies are enabled in GWT? If not what native javascript can do this?

Tags: javascript, gwt, cookies

As the title said...

Is it possible to tell if cookies are enabled in GWT?  If there is no baked in GWT support what javascript can do this?

If this is not possible I will just do it by checking the http request headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check `navigator.cookieEnabled` in browsers that support it.

If `navigator.cookieEnabled` is `undefined` (instead of true or false) then you can try setting a cookie and retrieving it.

**edit:** [`Cookies.isCookieEnabled()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/Cookies.html#isCookieEnabled%28%29) will return true/false if cookies are enabled -- it does this by [setting a cookie and checking if it was set](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#A1edwVHBClQ/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/Cookies.java&q=Cookies.java%20package%3ahttp://google-web-toolkit%5C.googlecode%5C.com&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc).